# Removing applications from deployment with Tomcat + Intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

In Intellij there's an option for deploying multiple apps at once on the same port (Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance). Where do you add/remove applications from the list that it should deploy on Tomcat start?

The Intellij docs say this, but I can't find what file it's describing.

> The Tomcat configuration files, among other things, may list the applications that should be deployed at the server start.

Comment: In the Intellij application folder (ie USER\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat in Windows) there's a tomcat folder where the  wars are stored. I deleted them all, but I still have 1 app that keeps running on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I was having. At some point an app had deployed to ROOT in my Tomcat server (Tomcat->webapps) and deleting it fixed my issue.